# how to visualize the complete graph in neo4j after importing the data and relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a question related to the `NEO4J`
when I create the nodes arround 40,000 and their relationships which are around 20,000 it means, 4K nodes and 6![enter image description here][1]K relationships which are less than 15MB for sure. 
when I run a query

```
"match (n) optional match (n)-[r]-() return n,r: "
```

it starts to load and after waiting for long time it returns nothing (in graphical form). But in the resultant file it shows how many nodes and relationships I have but no graphs . I want to see the complete graph of my data. is there anyway to see how does it look like, its only to visualize. When I limit the query till 800 it works.
 
Is there anything I need to change in settings or in my system memory?
any suggestion for that?

Answer (score 8):

The web console isn't very good for more than the hundreds of nodes scale.  I'd suggest looking at Gephi:

http://gephi.github.io/

Alternatively you could use Linkurious, an online tool:

https://linkurio.us/

If you want to roll your own there are a number of choices out there.  I like Sigma.js:

http://sigmajs.org/

Linkurious also has a library based on Sigma:

https://github.com/Linkurious/linkurious.js

EDIT: http://keylines.com/ is another online service like Linurious

Comment: thanks Brian, can i use all above mentioned tools with neo4j?

Comment: Yep!  Gephi needs a plugin installed.  For the JS tools you would need to do the integration

Comment: On another SO question I was reminded of http://keylines.com/ which you might also check out

Comment: hi brain, i tried to follow the gephi , i imported the neo4j data into gephi and in the end there was nothing, just one pop up warning and no results neither nodes nor relationships. i tried all possible ways i knew but still no success.

Comment: hi brain, are you sure about the linkrious because i have seen in the presentation given by jean on the graph connect platform that 500 nodes at a time i can view. Also, its not opensource right?

Comment: @ChHaXam Linkurious.js is open source. For pure display you can use the WebGL renderer that increase the limit to up to 20 000 nodes an 30 000 edges on average laptops. See http://slides.com/nicolasjoseph/largescalevis